# How to create dynamic text in label in SWT java?

Tags: java, swt, delay, windowbuilder

I am trying to write a code including a button and a label.

I want, when user click the button, the label shows TEXTA, then after three seconds it shows TEXTB.
What I see is when I click the button, the label wait for 3 seconds and shows TEXTB. 
Here is my code:

```
        Label lblFindModem = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblFindModem.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Ubuntu", 13, SWT.NORMAL));
        lblFindModem.setBounds(329, 164, 256, 28);
        lblFindModem.setText("Modem is not Initialized");

        Button btnFindModem = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);      
        btnFindModem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Someone Clicked the button");
                lblFindModem.setText("Unplug the modem for 3 seconds...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lblFindModem.setText("Plug the modem again.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can not simply use sleep in case of UI thread in swing or Eclipse RCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must **never** block the main SWT UI thread by calling things like `Thread.sleep`. This will make the app completely unresponsive and nothing will happen until the end of the sleep. It is vital than the UI code returns to the main `Display.readAndDispatch` loop quickly.

Instead you can use `Display.timerExec` to execute some code after a delay:

So replace your code

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
lblFindModem.setText("Plug the modem again.");
```

with:

```
Display.getCurrent().timerExec(3000, () -> lblFindModem.setText("Plug the modem again."));
```

(code assumes you are using Java 8 or later)